# Is it okay to use two identical ID in HTML and SVG?

Tags: html, svg

On my page there are two id attribute with the same value:

```
<div id="main">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 192 192">
    <defs>
      <path id="main"  ..... 
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Is it good to do so?

Comment: Thats up to your definition of good.  An id is meant to be unique and u will be no good if u write code that expects that. Though its not valid html "duplicate id" it will work without `major problems`

Comment: It's invalid, so no it's not good to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute's purpose is to give a unique identifier to an element, so that it can be referenced directly in various ways. Using duplicate values violates the HTML and SVG standards, and is likely to lead to problems.

The [WHATWG HTML/DOM Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) states this clearly:

> When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character.

The [W3C SVG Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#IDAttribute) uses the term "unique name", and references the XML Specification:

> Standard XML attribute for assigning a unique name to an element. Refer to the Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 Recommendation [XML10].

The [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) in turn formalises that uniqueness in these terms:

> Values of type ID MUST match the Name production. A name MUST NOT appear more than once in an XML document as a value of this type; i.e., ID values MUST uniquely identify the elements which bear them.

In practice, browsers are very tolerant of invalid markup, so you won't just get an error on the screen if you actually define duplicates. However, using that ID value for anything will be difficult - CSS selectors, JavaScript DOM APIs, and URL fragments may behave inconsistently from each other and between browsers.

Answer (score -3):

Strictly speaking not *invalid*.

Duplicate IDs (once, 20 to 15 years ago) had a meaning when IE was the dominant browser,
and all browsers since have copied IE behavior:

- IDs become global variables referencing the DOM Element (and still do in all browsers)
- Duplicate IDs return(ed) an Array(nodeList) of all Elements (Firefox no longer does nowadays)

See what your browser does:

```js
console.log("Global variable 'main' is:",typeof main,main.length,"elements");
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <svg>
      <defs> 
        <circle id="main"/>
      </defs>
      <path id="main" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

In general duplicate IDs are considered bad practice.
And they do break using SVG patterns, clips etc. where ID references are crucial.

In modern browsers you can use shadowDOM to encapsulate HTML (and CSS).
That allows for using the same (not duplicates anymore) IDs

Comment: I'm not sure what your first sentence is referring to. [The WHATWG HTML Spec makes it explicit that they must be unique](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Don't get me started on all the places where the formal documentation is "wrong"...
Press that "Run code snippet" button and see what your browser says. Absolutely nothing wrong using this knowledge in practice. But the documentation is "right" and browser vendors can change behavior in the next release. Like Mozilla did with duplicate IDs (don't recall when.. I think it was some 3 or 4 years ago).

Comment: "Absolutely nothing wrong using this knowledge ... browser vendors can change behavior in the next release". I think you've shown why your own statement is false there. The point of browser makers and users agreeing on standard behaviour is precisely so that your code *won't* break between releases, or in a browser that doesn't perfectly copy the "quirks" of the one you tested with. It's not perfect, but aiming for well-documented, standardised behaviour, and handling known bugs in browsers as a last resort, is definitely a better approach.

Comment: Correct. And that is why Chromium (now Microsoft has a stake in it) will forever handle duplicate IDs like I described above. The essence of the web is backward compatibility.. Don't break the web is the credo.  Mozilla broke that old IE behaviour, that's why every BOFH in the Microsoft world told users to use Chrome. And I dare say, that is why FireFox won't be around for long.  Old MSFT shit doesn't run on it... ah.. The Web, such harmony.

Comment: Yep, absolutely, everyone is going to choose their browser based on whether it supports one extremely odd DOM behaviour around duplicate IDs. Silly me, don't know why I ever doubted you.

Comment: No worries, there are always going to be people who turn the ignition and drive the car, and people who also understand what makes the car drive.